# Share (wizard-like) state between page with controller extension and page with controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension, standardcontroller, viewstate

I have a custom VF page to create new or edit records of Type `CustomObject__c`. Via a `Linker__c` object such records can be related to other `OtherCustomObject__c`.

To create such links I have a button on my custom new/edit page ...

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="CtrlExt">
        <apex:form >
            ...      
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Linker" columns="1">
                <apex:commandButton value="Link other objects" action="{!createLinks}" />
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!linkers}" var="links">
                    ....
```

...that should load another page where the user can select 0..n records of OtherCustomObject__c.

```
<apex:page controller="CtrlExt">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Link Selected Objects" action="{!doLink}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!doCancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
            ...
```

If he clicks Ok or Cancel he will come back to the previous page (**all of his edit should be still there**) and linker objects have been created from his selection.

**The problem here seems to be the shared state between the custom edit page with a controller extension and the select page which is not bound to a standard controller. 
How can harmonize the two different page types and share viewstate between them?**

```
public with sharing class CtrlExt {

    public  CtrlExt() {

    }

    public CtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) {

    }

    public PageReference doSelect() {
        return Page.selectOtherObjects;
    }

    public PageReference doLink() {
        // create Linker records
        return Page.customEditNew;
    }

    public PageReference doCancel() {
        return Page.customEditNew;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it an option to use one visualforce and have different sections displayed or not using Rendered?

Comment: Not really an option as each single page already is complex enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the same page signature for the second page too:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="CtrlExt">
```

that I assume would ensure that the state is transferred? The second page logic can just ignore anything related to the `ApexPages.StandardController`. One way to tell which page the controller is operating on would be:

```
Boolean onFirstPage = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl() == Page.First.getUrl();
Boolean onSecondPage = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl() == Page.Second.getUrl();
```

Navigation between the pages would need to use view state preserving components like `apex:commandButton` and `apex:commandLink`.